# Sorting Array from Higest to Lowest

Tags: java, arrays

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] x;
    x= new int [3];
    x[0]=4;
    x[1]=1;
    x[2]=2;
    x[3]=3;
    x=sortArray (x);
    System.out.println (x[2]);
}

public static int indexOfMaxInRange(int[] A, int i){
    int maxIndex=A[0];
    while (i < A.length) {
        if (A[i]>maxIndex){
            maxIndex= A[i];
        }
        i++;
    }
    return maxIndex;
}

 public static int[] swapElement (int[] A,int i1,int i2) {
    int i1value=A[i1];
    int i2value=A[i2];
    A[i1]=A[i2value];
    A[i2]=A[i1value];
    return A;
}

 public static int[] sortArray (int[] A) {
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        int x=indexOfMaxInRange (A,i);
        swapElement (A,x,i);
    }
    return A;
}
```

This keeps on returning on with an error.
I can't seem to find what's wrong with my program.
The objective of the program is to sort an array highest from lowest.

Comment: You really should say what the error is, but it looks like an index out of range error in your swapElement method, because you're using the value in the array as the index.
Also note your algorithm is O(n^2) because you're iterating from the start of the sequence for every element of the sequence.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow. You've gotten a couple downvotes - probably because questions like "why isn't this code working" should include a *clear problem definition*: what's going wrong, including any errors or erroneous output, along with the *minimum complete example* of code necessary to *reproduce* the problem. Check out the [how do I write a good question? page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider editing your question :)

Comment: You probably should include whats going wrong, and where you suspect the error to be

Answer (score 0):

Let's start off with x[3] = 3. Since you declared x to be of size 3, your max index would be 2. That was probably your original error, **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsError** - which basically means you are trying to assign a value to an index of the array that is not within the range of [0, len(array) - 1]. So, either increase the size of the array or don't assign an element to index 3.

Also, for future reference, letting us know what  error you get would be helpful.

When calling functions, try to not have a space between the function name and the opening parenthesis. It will still compile, I believe, but it is weird to read. Also, add spaces around the equals sign. For example:

```
int x=indexOfMaxInRange (A,i);
```

should be:

```
int x = indexOfMaxInRange(A,i);
```

From what I gather you are implementing selection sort, where you get the max of the whole array, place it as the first element, and find the highest of the array while ignoring the first element and placing that element as the second element in the array. And so on and so forth.

Your swap function looks good as does your sortArray function, however, your indexMaxOfRange function is incorrect. I will leave you to fix that function for yourself, but I will say that indexMaxOfRange is expecting an index to be returned, and at no place in that function are you assigning maxIndex to be an index.